# Display array (read and processed from text file) elements to new lines in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've below code where user can upload text file. I tried to display output in `div` after splitting it using `@` as split character. Array elements stored into variables are displayed correctly with new line in `alert` but are printed in a single line in `div`.

```js
  function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {

    var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
    if (!files.length) {
      alert('Please select a file!');
      return;
    }
    var file = files[0];
    var start = parseInt(opt_startByte) || 0;
    var stop = parseInt(opt_stopByte) || file.size - 1;
    var reader = new FileReader();

    // If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
      if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
    var test = evt.target.result;
  var htmlstring = test.split('@');
  var data = htmlstring.join('\r\n');
        document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = data;
  alert(data); //with line-break
  alert(htmlstring); // without line-break
      }
    };
    var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
  }
  document.querySelector('.readBytesButtons').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
      var startByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-startbyte');
      var endByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-endbyte');
      readBlob(startByte, endByte);
    }
  }, false);
```

```css
  #byte_content {
    margin: 5px 0;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  #byte_range { margin-top: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="files" name="file" /> Read bytes: 
<span class="readBytesButtons">
  <button>entire file</button>
</span>
<div id="byte_content"></div>
```

Text file data:

```
this is some text @2135311 164 @df fdg
```

Current output:

```
this is some text 2135311 164 df fdg
```

Desired output:

```
this is some text 
2135311 164 
df fdg
```

Comment: Off topic: You're loading jQuery but still doing many things longhand. You might look into ID and class selectors and the `attr()` method, which simplify your code quite a bit.

Comment: To me, it appears that you are just adding a carriage return and line feed between the strings before displaying to the HTML.  If you view source I think you will find that it appears as you expected in the HTML.  You could put a <pre> tag around it, or you could modify the join to include a <br> tag.

Comment: @Tom, tried but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to render data in HTML not plain text:
 
Instead of `\r\n` use `<br>`.
Instead of `.textContent` use `innerHTML`

> ```
> var data = htmlstring.join('<br>');
> document.getElementById('byte_content').innerHTML = data;
> ```

### Demo

```js
function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {

  var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
  if (files.length < 1) {
    alert('Please select a file!');
    return;
  }
  var file = files[0];
  var start = parseInt(opt_startByte) || 0;
  var stop = parseInt(opt_stopByte) || file.size - 1;
  var reader = new FileReader();

  // If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
  reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
      var test = evt.target.result;
      var htmlstring = test.split('@');
      var data = htmlstring.join('<br>');
      document.getElementById('byte_content').innerHTML = data;
      alert(data); //with line-break
      alert(htmlstring); // without line-break
    }
  };
  var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
  reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
}
document.querySelector('.readBytesButtons').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
    var startByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-startbyte');
    var endByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-endbyte');
    readBlob(startByte, endByte);
  }
}, false);
```

```css
#byte_content {
  margin: 5px 0;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#byte_range {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="files" name="file" /> Read bytes:
<span class="readBytesButtons">
  <button>entire file</button>
</span>
<div id="byte_content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replacing `div` with `textarea` tag to display content it's working fine.